# React Router - Grouping routes in variables or components

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router

I am trying to set up my router to handle a multilingual site, and having trouble with the modularization of the routes.

My routes file looks like this:

```js
import React from 'react'
import { Redirect, Route, Switch, useRouteMatch } from 'react-router-dom'
import FrontPage from './views/front-view'
import SearchPortal from './views/search-portal-view'
import DocumentView from './views/document-view'
import ErrorView from './views/error-view'

export const Routes = (): JSX.Element => {
  const { path } = useRouteMatch()
  return (
    <>
      <Route path={`${path}/search`} component={SearchPortal} />
      <Route path={`${path}/document/`} component={DocumentView} />
      <Route path={`${path}/error`} component={ErrorView} />
      <Route path={`${path}/`} exact component={FrontPage} />
      <Route component={ErrorView} />
    </>
  )
}

export const DefaultRoutes = (
  <>
    <Route path='/search'>
      {console.log('Search Route')}
      <Redirect to='/en/search' />
    </Route>
    <Route path='/document'>
      {console.log('document route')}
      <Redirect to='/en/document' />
    </Route>
    <Route path='/error'>
      {console.log('error route')}
      <Redirect to='/en/error' />
    </Route>
    <Route path='/' exact>
      {console.log('home route')}
      <Redirect to='/en/' />
    </Route>
  </>
)

export const LangRoutes = (): JSX.Element => (
  <Switch>
    <Route path='/:lang([a-z]{2})' component={Routes} />
    {DefaultRoutes}
    <Route component={ErrorView} /> {/* Rendered when nothing else works */}
  </Switch>
)
```

Everything works except for if I have an invalid URL without a language on it. (eg. localhost:3000/invalidPath). If the path becomes invalid *after* the language, it works fine, and the Error page is displayed.

If, however, I copy and paste the contents of the `DefaultRoutes` (without the Fragment) into `LangRoutes`, then everything works properly.

Why is this? And is there a better way to go about doing this?